# QuickBooks Integration with Salesforce getting java.lang.NullPointerException exception

Tags: quickbooks-api

I am integrating Salesforce with QuickBooks with QB Online V3 API, OAuth is successful but when I am trying to fetch all invoices from Quickbooks SandBox Company but getting the following response:-

> {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while
>   processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException","code":"10000","element":"SystemFailureError"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2015-04-01T05:26:47.443-07:00"}

This is the endpoint:-
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1238827727/query?query=select * from invoice

Thanks in Advance